# CSS edits in Chrome Console work but not when deployed on live site?

Tags: html, css

I wanted to add some negative margins to this particular section I see in Chrome Console ([link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObTSx.png)):

```
.woocommerce div.product div.images .woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper {
    -webkit-transition: all cubic-bezier(.795,-.035,0,1) .5s;
    transition: all cubic-bezier(.795,-.035,0,1) .5s;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
```

The change I want to make is to add a negative margin. Thus, when I made the change in Chrome Console, I see the desired effect.

```
.woocommerce div.product div.images .woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper {
    -webkit-transition: all cubic-bezier(.795,-.035,0,1) .5s;
    transition: all cubic-bezier(.795,-.035,0,1) .5s;
    margin: -50px;
    padding: 0;
```

However, when I try to insert this as CSS on my website using the code below, I do not see the change happening. Is there a reason for that? The code I used in my CSS is as follows:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .woocommerce div.product div.images .woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper{
    margin: -50px !important;   
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Maybe you have javascript controlling this margin and setting this margin to zero, try to find this logic, or try to override it.

Comment: @AliAli, thanks. already placed !important there. How should I override it?

Comment: I posted an answer for you, let me know if you need any help applying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using !important will only override CSS.

Try this JQuery to override your existing code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($)
{
$('.woocommerce div.product div.images .woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper').css('margin', '-50px');
});
```